# GWT -- Retain search text value in html text box after filtering in cell table

Tags: gwt

I created a custom header for cell table in gwt. it consists of a filter text box and below that column name. I am able to filter the column data. Not able to retain the search text after the filtering the cell table. Text box is becoming empty after filtering.
I have used html text box in the header. Please help me to retain search text value after filtering cell table.  I have added my code below for onbrowserevent...
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem, NativeEvent event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(context, elem, event);

```
    int eventType = event.getKeyCode();

    if (eventType == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
        InputElement inputElement = getInputElement(elem);
        setValue(inputElement.getValue());

        if(filterHandler != null){
            filterHandler.onFilter(getValue());
        }
        inputElement.setAttribute("value", inputElement.getValue());
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
}

protected InputElement getInputElement(Element parent) {
    Element elem = parent.getElementsByTagName("input").getItem(0);
    assert (elem.getClass() == InputElement.class);
    return elem.cast();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your column's `Header` return the search query from its `getValue`, it'll be passed to your cell's `render()` method.